# python class read-only attributes (in datetime)

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I know that a quick way of setting an attribute to be private is to use `__` before an attribute (**corrected later as this is actually for name mangling, not for restriction of access**), or use @property

But, I found that for a python standard library module, for example, [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#module-datetime), this was set a different way?

To explain my question, please go to [the source code of datetime](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/3.6/Lib/datetime.py)

Let's take class `timedelta` as an example:

```
class timedelta:
    ...
    ...
    ... 

timedelta.min = timedelta(-999999999)
timedelta.max = timedelta(days=999999999, hours=23, minutes=59, seconds=59,
                          microseconds=999999)
timedelta.resolution = timedelta(microseconds=1)
```

**The class attributes was set outside of the class? why?**

and if I:

```
import datetime
d= datetime.timedelta(days=1, hours=12)
print(d)
print(d.max)  # >>> 999999999 days, 23:59:59.999999
print(type(d.max))  # >>> <class 'datetime.timedelta'>

d.max = 1000  # regardless of the reason, if I just want to do this
# >>> AttributeError: 'datetime.timedelta' object attribute 'max' is read-only
```

**I wonder where does this `AttributeError` coming from? I can not find in anywhere in the source code that this error message will be raised?**

Thanks!

Comment: There are no private attributes in Python. double-underscore name-mangling does *name-mangling*, it doesn't restrict access.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I do know that for a fact as `__private` is disguised under `_Class__private`, so it is not truly read-only . That makes me even more wondering how they set it up to make `timedelta.max` read-only

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Got it, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The class attributes was set outside of the class? why?

`timedelta` doesn't exist when the body of the `timedelta` class is being executed. You have to execute all of the code in the `class timedelta:` block before the class object is created and can be used on its own.

> I wonder where does this AttributeError coming from? I can not find in anywhere in the source code that this error message will be raised?

The `datetime` module is written in pure Python but [tries to use](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/09dc2f508c8513e0466a759cc27a09108c1e55c2/Lib/datetime.py#L2412) a faster module [written in C](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9f1b7b93f5f0ef589e7b272e127cacf4ce5d23f1/Modules/_datetimemodule.c) if it can. The pure Python code works as you'd expect:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.modules['_datetime'] = None  # prevent the C module from loading
>>> from datetime import timedelta
>>> timedelta.min = 5
>>> timedelta.min
5
```

The `timedelta` class has [`tp_flags`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyTypeObject.tp_flags) set to [`Py_TPFLAGS_DEFAULT | Py_TPFLAGS_BASETYPE`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/9f1b7b93f5f0ef589e7b272e127cacf4ce5d23f1/Modules/_datetimemodule.c#L2698). You can only set the attributes of objects which include the [`Py_TPFLAGS_HEAPTYPE` flag](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/ce5b0e9db1b9698e6ffc43ae41cf3a22ca5a6ba6/Objects/typeobject.c#L3224-L3228).

Comment: Thank you so much for the clear explanation! As a beginner who just started to learn python not too long ago (and only python), I may have gone too far asking this question at this early stage.

Comment: If I can ask a further question based on your answer. How can one tell if a .py file is trying to use a module written in C? From the datetime.py file, I can only see CPython in comments, but no else where

Comment: @Code_Control_jxie0755: If you look at the very bottom of `datetime.py`, it has code that `try`s to do `from _datetime import *`. Using an underscore prefixed module name is the Python 3 standard for the C extension module backing a module implemented in pure Python, and the pattern of "define all the Python stuff, but then see if we can't replace most/all of it with equivalents from the accelerator module" is fairly common.

Answer (score 2):

That is not the source code of the date-time module used by the CPython interpreter. The CPython source implements a lot of the standard library in C for performance reasons. They do provide Python-only implementations (which I believe are relied upon by PyPy in many instances, for example).

The source code for `datetime` is actually here:

https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Modules/_datetimemodule.c

Access is restricted at the C-level.

Note, double-underscore name-mangling does *name-mangling*, it doesn't restrict access.